# In Nginx How to handle HTTP requests without the leading slash "/"?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, rewrite, 400

I have an Nginx proxy in front my application. I recently learned that, HTTP requests can be made without a leading slash also.

**For Example:**

```
POST acme/_search HTTP/1.1
```

In cases like this, Nginx always returns `400 Bad Request`. I would like to handle this case by  either modifying the request_uri or rewriting the request path with a leading slash.

So that the request_uri `acme/_search` will be rewritten as `/acme/_search` . Any requests with the leading slash are working fine and returns `200`.

I've tried handling it using a rewrite statement in the server block like below:

```
server {
    listen 9000;

    if ($request_uri ~* ^[^\/]) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upstream_http;
        allow all;
    }
 }
```

^ What I'm trying to do in the above block is, Check if the `request_uri` doesn't start with a leading slash & if yes, rewrite the path with a leading slash.

But this configuration is not working. I still get the `400 Bad Request` message logged & returned by Nginx.

I'm using to telnet to make the example request:

```
telnet localhost 9000

POST acme/_search HTTP/1.1
```

Would like to know how these kind of HTTP requests without a leading slash can be handled using Nginx as a proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately, 400 means that Nginx does not understand the request. There is nothing you can do in Nginx.

Comment: Adding "HTTP/1.1" to your request doesn't make it HTTP/1.1 compliant.  You'll find ample documentation on the web about HTTP, the P stands for "Protocol".  If you don't accept it, Nginx doesn't accept your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx only allows requests like the one below to start without leading `/`:

```
GET <schema>://example.com
```

This can be seen in [nginx v1.20.1](http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.20.1.tar.gz) `ngx_http_parse.c` source code file. The parsing of request line after HTTP method is done starting from line 280 in the file.

It does not support arbitrary text strings after `GET`. You cannot modify this behavior with any `rewrite` rules, since the request validation is done much earlier than `rewrite` rule processing.

I am also very confident that nginx implementation is according to the HTTP RFC. Therefore I think you have misunderstood something here.

Comment: RFC 7230 sections 5.3.1 confirms this.